# Models of a JSON in the wrong orientation in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am building a website with 3D graphics using THREE JavaScript, I am trying to import the following scene to site but in the site all the objects are facing to the inside of the planet: [The scene problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33gJX.png)

Here is the code I am using to import the scene:

```
//ADDING GEOMETRY
        var objects = [];
        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

        loader.load('models/planeta-NoMerge.json', function( obj ){
            scene.add( obj );

            scene.traverse(function( children ){
                objects.push(children);
            });

        });
```

I´m doing some raycasting because I need to show a different scene if the user clicks on a model.

And if you need something else, please let me know: D

Comment: camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1); easiest solution is to change the camera direction instead of changing the loaded models.

Comment: another solution is to set the scale of the model to a negative value to invert it, so if you need it to be turned 180 degrees you could set e.g. the X scale to -1

Comment: @SimonHyll thanks for the quick answer. I understand the change in scale you are telling me but would it work in a scene? I am importing an scene but with all meshes separated into objects. Thanks again

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think so, try it and find out? :)

Answer (score 0):

All in all the probem is not in code you have posted. I have had similar issues here and then, but I could fix it by tweaking the export settings. There you can flip normals, include/exclude several things like Material, Bones, Animations, etc...

So it's hard to tell which Settings you need, since that is up to your needs, but playing arround with the settings will bring you further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @philipp. I am exporting it to json in Blender so do you know where do a i have to play around with the settings? It has to be in the modelling or in the exporter section? Thanks again :D

Comment: Yes! In Blender, choose export Three json and the those Settings can be found on the left of the file save view.

Comment: Ohh, I found them. Thanks, I´m going to look at them. But i dont see any option like "reverse normals" :/

Comment: No? Well then you probably need to do that in the model ;) Those Problems you are in can depend on a whole bunch of reasons, not everything Blender can, is what THREE can, that might be some material settings, render options and so on… I would recommend to start with quite simple Materials, just to make sure that all normals and stuff alike is right, than add more advanced things…

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I will take a look to all the settings then and go back to basic materials. Thank you very much.

Comment: Tip: use the Collada format instead when exporting from Blender, its developer is waaay better (last I heard it was the original creator or somehing like that of the Collada format that also develops the Collada exporter for Blender), the format is better (includes more stuff) and Three.js has a Collada object loader so you don't have to change your code that much to use it.